# How to set an object’s rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set the rotation to the angle of the mouse to the object, but it's just going in a random direction.

```cs
mousePos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition)

Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - gameObject.transform.position;

float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
Debug.Log(angle);
      
if(angle == transform.rotation.z)
{

}
else
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
}
```

Comment: It is appearing to go in random direction because of the sampling rate.  You are sampling too slow.  You need to sample at least 2x the rotation speed to see results.

Comment: Is `Quaternion.Euler` in degrees?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes it is.